# Upgraded Visual Studio, now I get hundreds of errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, upgrade, webmatrix

Just installed WebMatrix and upgraded Visual Studio 2012 to Version 4.5.50709 SP1Rel. Now when I open my webapplication I get a bunch of errors of this type:

```
'IIf' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'IsNothing' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'IsNumeric' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

I get so many errors that I even get this:

```
Error   104 Maximum number of errors has been exceeded.
```

Comment: Those are methods found in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll. Check if the project references are still valid or if you have some using/imports missing.

Comment: I get no errors regarding references (might be because of max errors reached) - how can I check my references?

Comment: Expand the project node in the Solution Explorer window, then expand references and check if there is anything missing there. (Microsoft.VisualBasic should be 10.0. with runtime v.4.0.30319 and Specific Version set to False)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help - it turned out that the MySQL connector I referred was uninstalled in the process, reinstalling MySql connector solved the issue. By the way: I do not need a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that during WebMatrix installation or Visual Studio upgrade MySql Connector version 6.5.4.0 was also installed.

Somehow MySql Connector v. 5.1.5, which my project were referring was uninstalled in the process.

Reinstalling MySql connector 5.1.5 solved the issue. Changing the reference to the new MySql connector would probably also solve the issue.

Comment: That's a remarkably bizarre explanation for these error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem in VS 2012 when attempting to copy over an old version of a program I received from another colleague.

As muleskinner says, it is not a reference issue to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`...

When you try to add that as a reference it will tell you that it is already automatically referenced by the build system.

It turns out that even though `Microsoft.VisualBasic` is automatically referenced, the project didn't actually have the namespace imported.

You can add it by going to the properties of your project -> `References` -> And then make sure that `Microsoft.VisualBasic` is checked in the list of namespaces at the bottom.

At least that worked for me and cleared up all my errors. Wasn't relishing trying to change all my IIf statements into the more traditional format...